# How to make custom url while using name router-outlet?

Tags: angular, url-routing, named-routing

Here i don't want this (`sidebar:cart-page`) please help me?

[image]

I wanted to make inner cart component common while searching based on tag and also don't want (`sidebar:cart-page`)

[image]

[image]

Comment: We’re happy to help you, but in order to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some guidelines to follow: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Angular need to know which `router-outlet` should be used. One way you can go is to use `child-routes`. Then you only have own `router-outlet` in the main component, and each child component has a `router-outlet`, too.

##### Example

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first-component',
    component: FirstComponent, // this is the component with the <router-outlet> in the template
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child-a', // child route path
        component: ChildAComponent, // child route component that the router renders
      },
      {
        path: 'child-b',
        component: ChildBComponent, // another child route component that the router renders
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And children can have children, two. So your route looks different and without the `(sidebar:cart-page)`.